# Best tools to start for 2D graphic animation for Physics?

Tags: animation, vegas-pro

I want to make an animation like this. What do you call them? And is it possible to do it in Sony Vegas? How do I get started?

These came from the video of Consumed by the Apocalypse by Lemmino:

[image: Consumed by the Apocalypse: 1:22]

[image: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nx2-4l4s4Nw]

Comment: This sort of question is not a good fit here because a) multiple questions, b) very subjective and c) it is the subject of entire courses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just my thoughts:

It looks like it (motion graphics) could be done with Vegas but the industry standard is to do it with After Effects, probably in partnership with something like Illustrator.

TBH I am not too familiar with Vegas but I have seen its output; AE on the other hand has been around for a long time and I have seen physics, mathematical, medical, etc, motions graphics and video done with that as the norm.

(Based on doing motion graphics eons ago)

If you are new to this, best bet is to look at tutorials on youtube and get stuck in for a long ride and perhaps quite a learning curve.